# Sentinel 2 satellite images API

Tags: sentinel-2, api, satellite

I want to download or reach Sentinel 2 images as png, jpg. I used [Copernicus Open Access Hub](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/) but it is not so clear, can someone explain how to download one satellite images with ROI and time?

Comment: use the OpenHub, right-click to draw extents, fill in the criteria to query (top left of your hand side), and use your account to download; have you tried this?

Comment: I downloaded something but their extentions were not jpg or png , it was zip file and there were a lot of files which are not images.

Comment: I think you are new with satellite imageries? my advice is to read the documentation and learn how raster data & satellite data work first. Those folders contain multiple bands that reflect certain frequencies. they capture from infrared-ultraviolet. what you want is probably bands 2,3 and 4; combine it as a single raster and export it as png with QGIS/ArcGIS. That's what I've been doing. Idk if there are other efficient methods besides using python/Google Earth Engine.

Comment: @sutan Thanks for the advice, exactly I am new.